# String Editing in R - Taking Out Repetition

Tags: string, r, repeat

I'm working with some character data in R, and I have some parts that have (foo)(foo) in the middle of the string. Is there anyway to automatically find those repetitions, and remove them (representing them as (foo) in the same position)?

I'm wondering if a possible solution is to use strsplit by ), and check if there is any equivalency, and then just reappend the ) back. Would this work?

Ex. string: "abc def (foo)(foo) abc def"

Comment: It is not clear how does your string look. It is better to give and example of this string.

Comment: For example "abc def (foo)(foo) abc def". But my method works. First split by spaces, then split by ), then test for equivalence, and delete the second one.

Comment: You should add this to your question and add the expected result also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a perl regular expression substitution within R as in the following example:

```
test <- "abc def (foo)(foo) abc def"
gsub('(\\(\\w+\\))\\1','\\1',test,perl=TRUE)
```

Alternatively, you can run a perl one-liner to clean the data beforehand:

```
echo "abc def (foo)(foo) abc def\n" | perl -ne 's/(\(\w+\))\1/$1/gi;print'
```

Answer (score 2):

here a possibility to keep only the 1st repeated element in a sequence :

```
gsub("(.+)\\1+","\\1", x, perl=T)
```

HTH